# Getting a NULL when calling getElementById

Tags: java, jsoup

I have the HTML (partial) shown below. I want to find the element using:

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Element elem = doc.getElementById("date-2011-04-23");
```

But I always get a `NULL`. Can anyone help me? As a check, I've also code this using VB.NET and I can access this element.

```
<td class="" id="date-2011-04-23" data-week="3" data-wkday="6">...</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your tag looks like:

```
<td class="" id="date-2011-04-23" data-week="3" data-wkday="6">...</td>
```

You can use the [JSoup Selector API](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) for this:

```
for( Element element : doc.select("#date-2011-04-23") )
{
    // Do something here
}
```

If you need only the first Element:

```
Element element = doc.select("#date-2011-04-23").first();
```

Comment: I'll try that.  Why the # sign?

Comment: `#` is the 'keyword' for the ID of a tag. eg "#abc" selects the tag with the id=abc.

Comment: I'[l still getting a null using select.  I don't get it.  How do I post the complete HTML element to stackoverflow?  it does something to HTML when I post.  Alternatively, the page I want to parse is the schedule for the Philadelphia Phillies.  this URL:  http://mlb.mlb.com/schedule/index.jsp?c_id=PHI#y=2011&m=4&calendar=DEFAULT

Comment: You should put your HTML / Java Code into Code-Tags.

Comment: Btw. can you post a bit more html code? you can also test `"td#date-2011-04-23"`

Comment: Strange ... if i use the html as in my post i get `<td class="" id="date-2011-04-23" data-week="3" data-wkday="6">...</td>` with your code as well as with mine. Did you check your document for `null`?

Comment: Doc is OK.  not null.  here's my code                                              org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = (org.jsoup.nodes.Document) Jsoup.connect(philies_url).get();                                                                                                                           org.jsoup.nodes.Element elem = doc.select("td#date-2011-04-23").first();

Comment: Why do use a cast for the `get()` Method?

Comment: I dont know.  I'm not a java guy.  I normally code in VB.NET.  I removed the cast.  Makes no difference.  I still get a null.

Comment: Please post some more html and your whole java code. Maybe there's something wrong with it.

Comment: YOu can see the HTML at that link - Phillies Schedule.  I can't post all the java code - it's a small part of a larger project.  but I only have 2 lines that use Jsoup.   Document doc = Jsoup.connect(philies_url).get();    Element elem = doc.select("#date-2011-04-24").first();

Comment: I used JSoup in another project and it worked fine.  Different HTML.  But I used a select.  My select was this:   Elements elements = doc.select("dd");

Comment: if I do this:   Elements elements = doc.select("#date-2011-04-24");    How then do I get the first element?

Comment: I tried this, but it gives me out of bounds esception.  Element first = elements.get(0);

Comment: size of the Elements is 0.  So this fails too.

Comment: ah, I got this to work.  This uses the ID of a div tag.  However, The element I want, the one with the date, is a cell within a table.  Element elem = doc.select("#bodyWrap").first();

Comment: Does the type of tag make any difference?  It should not, correct?

Comment: here's what I have found.  Any tag name with a dash in the name causes this issue.   I tried 3 or 4 tags with and without a dash in the name, and I get this result consistently.

Comment: Are you the author of Jsoup?

Comment: You also get the first element by calling `elements.first()`. However, if `elements` is empty it won't return something.

Comment: What version of jsoup do you use? With 1.7.1 my code (as well as yours) as posted above works correctly. Btw. i'm not the author if jsoup :-)

Comment: After all that comments i lost a bit of overview, can you select proper tags now?

Comment: here's what I have found. Any tag name with a dash in the name causes this issue. I tried 3 or 4 tags with and without a dash in the name, and I get this result consistently.

Comment: What version of Jsoup are you using? If < 1.7.1 you should consider an update.

Comment: I am using 1.7.1.  I saw a bug opened for this in the respository for JSoup bugs.  https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/search?q=dash

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not finding that content in the HTML is that the schedule is loaded from a JSON file by the browser executing Javascript, then adding it to the browser DOM. Jsoup does not execute Javascript, so it only can see what is in the source HTML.

If you use a debugging proxy like Charles (or the debugging network pane in Chrome / Firefox), you can see all the requests a browser makes to render a page. In this example, the schedule data is coming from http://mlb.mlb.com/gen/schedule/phi/2011_4.json